# jsoup получить потомков первого уровня

Tags: java, jsoup

Всем привет. Есть страничка, пример:

```
<div>
   <div></div>(1)
   <div>
      <div></div>(2)
   </div>(3)
</div>
```

Я выделил первый элемент div. Как мне получить элементы 1 и 3, при этом игнорирую 2?

Comment: А у корневого элемента какой-нибудь идентификатор есть?

Comment: <div class="content main">

Comment: `Elements resultDivs = doc.select("div.content.main" > div");` не подойдет?

Comment: нет, к сожалению в таком случае он всех потомков выделит, а мне нужны только потомки первого уровня

Comment: Да быть не может. Это именно непосредственных потомков выбирает без вложенностей

Comment: Все оказалось куда проще, использовал метод .children()

Answer (score 1):

```
final Stream<Element> stream = doc.getElementsByTag("div").stream();
        stream.forEach(element ->
        {
            //проверка на контекст
        }
```